# Como alterar a cor do texto em um JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing

Estou desenvolvendo um chat e ele usa uma `JTextPane` para exibir as mensagens em cores diferentes para cada usuário. Porém, não sei como posso trocar as cores do texto desse componente.

Exemplo:
Temos duas pessoas(João e Pedro), quando recebo uma mensagem de Pedro pela primeira vez o chat escolhe uma cor e então usará está cor para todas as mensagens de João, enquanto dará outra cor para as mensagens de Pedro, mas todas elas apareceram em uma mesma `JTextPane`, os usuários são identificados pelo seu endereço IP.

Algo parecido com isto:

<kbd>[image: imagem demonstrando o efeito desejado]</kbd>

Comment: O que já tentou fazer? Adicione na pergunta o que já fez ate agora.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A partir de um exemplo retirado [deste link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/ExtensionofJTextPanethatallowstheusertoeasilyappendcoloredtexttothedocument.htm), fiz um exemplo onde é possível alterar o texto em tempo de execução, utilizando as classes [`StyleContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyleContext.html) e [`AttributeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/AttributeSet.html). Para usar, basta adaptar o componente `ColorPane` no seu código, e passar a cor desejada junto com o texto no método `append`, conforme o usuário que estiver digitando.

Segue o código:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class ChangeColorPaneTest extends JFrame {

    JTextField field;
    ColorPane pane;
    boolean alternate = true;

    public void startFrame() {
        pane = new ColorPane();
        pane.setBackground(new Color(245, 245, 245));

        field = new JTextField();
        field.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(getSize().width, 25));
        field.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //action apenas para fins de exemplificação
                Color textColor = alternate ? Color.red : Color.BLUE;
                pane.append(textColor, field.getText());
                alternate = !alternate;
                field.setText("");
            }
        });

        JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(pane);
        scrollpane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        setTitle("ColorPane example");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(scrollpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(field, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        field.requestFocusInWindow();
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    class ColorPane extends JTextPane {

        public void append(Color c, String s) {
            //implementação utilizando StyleContext
            StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
            AttributeSet aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY,
                    StyleConstants.Foreground, c);

            // tamanho do texto já no component
            int len = getDocument().getLength(); 
            // altera a posicao do cursor para o fim(se não houver seleção)
            setCaretPosition(len); 
            setCharacterAttributes(aset, false);
            //O \n é apenas para o texto ser quebrado
            //para fins de demonstracao
            //se não houver seleção, adiciona o texto no fim
            replaceSelection(s.concat("\n")); 
        }

    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ChangeColorPaneTest pane = new ChangeColorPaneTest();
                pane.startFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Resultado:

<kbd>[image: gif animado com demonstração do código]</kbd>

**Referência**:

[How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes(Documentação)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html)

Answer (score 1):

Se for para mudar apenas a cor do texto, faça assim:

```
textPane.setForeground(Color.RED);
```

E se for para mudar a cor de fundo (background), faça assim:

```
textPane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
```

E não se esqueça de importar a classe `Color`:

```
import java.awt.Color;
```

Comment: Isso muda toda a fonte, e se você ler a pegunta com atenção, verá que ele quer alterar linha pro linha. Essa solução não servirá para isso.

Answer (score -1):

Em primeiro lugar você cria o objeto para poder modifica-lo

```
private jTextPane1 = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
```

em seguida você poderá acessar ele para modificar das seguintes formas.

Você pode estar colocando direto no construtor por exemplo:

```
    public NovoJFrame() {
      initComponents();
      //use setForeground para mudar a cor e Color pra colocar o código rgb da cor
      jTextPane1.setForeground(new Color(255,0,0));

}
```

ou você pode colocar ele em alguma função como por exemplo:

```
public mudaCor(){
//use setForeground para mudar a cor e Color pra colocar o código rgb da cor
  jTextPane1.setForeground(new Color(255,0,0));
}
```

Comment: Se o que ele quiser for alternar a cor do texto a cada mensagem, isso não vai funcionar.

Comment: Estava querendo utilizar as funções de estilo dessa classe. Não aplicar a todo texto...

Comment: Altere a cor no objeto JLabel que será inserido no JPane e não diretamente no JPane

Comment: Sua resposta não é explica isso. Se foi feita uma pergunta, é porque o OP não tem noção de como fazer isso.

Answer (score -1):

Apenas como uma alternativa, se for aprender tente usar JavaFX. É muito mais simples e muito mais dinâmico, nele você usaria apenas `label1.setTextFill(Color.web("#0076a3"));`, na verdade tem até um editor chamado Scene Builder ele faz tudo. Olha o que da para criar. Dá até para criar jogos de tão perfeito e não ocupa nada de espaço.

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: A pergunta é sobre swing e você responde com javafx?

Comment: A partir do java 9 swing vai ser retirado, não acha melhor ele ja ir aprendendo JavaFX que vai substitui-lo?

Item 6 e esta previsto para no próximo java .
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html#6

Comment: @diegofm A princípio, pensei a mesma coisa que você. Mas, considerando que o(a) AP está no início do projeto, acho que essa resposta veio a calhar sim, especialmente porque não é só um link, mas mostra a linha de código usada para resolver o problema. Não é muito diferente do clássico "Use JodaTime" nas respostas relacionadas a tempo em Java.

Comment: @PabloAlmeida se for assim, toda pergunta de swing então vão começar a responder com javafx. O OP não pede alternativas em outras tecnologias, pede ajuda em relação a um componente. Isso poderia ser um comentário, afinal, o campo resposta é para sugestões que resolvam o problema, não sei se mandar o OP aprender outra tecnologia é uma solução.

Comment: @diegofm Em geral, concordo com você, mas toda regra tem exceção. Nesse caso específico, pelos motivos citados -- iminente substituição da Swing como framework de GUI oficial e o fato de que o impacto em mudar de tecnologia nessa etapa é mínimo -- achei que foi uma boa, sim. Claro que a resposta poderia estar melhor formulada, mas não recomendei a exclusão por esse motivo. Mas entendo perfeitamente se pensar diferente-- fiquei um bom tempo "em cima do muro" na análise.

Comment: Outra coisa, a resposta sugere outra tecnologia, mas não ensina como resolver o problema em outra tecnologia. Cada um tem seu criterio pelo que to vendo, ainda sim, não vejo isso como uma resposta válida, uma vez que não resolve o problema da pergunta, já que a finalidade da resposta seria essa.

Comment: Aquela linha de código na resposta ( `label1.setTextFill(Color.web("#0076a3"));`) não faz o que o(a) autor(a) da resposta disse que faz? Se não fizer, a resposta está factualmente errada, mas aí já é outro problema.

Comment: setTextFill faz exatamente o que ele pede, não é só para o Label, serve também para o TextArea e TextField como ele quer mudar de cor a cada mensagem enviada, basta ele mudar o código HTML de cada mensagem, poderia ser mais completo como Pablo disse o código ja pronto com a mudança. Mas acho que o Autor ja foi até embora, ele nem se pronunciou se é de interesse dele, já deve ter até conseguido e o diegofm brigando para ver se tira a minha resposta. Verdade nem perco mais meu tempo ajudando os outros. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/text-settings.htm

Comment: Eu não estou brigando pra tirar sua resposta, só não concordei que apenas mandar o OP aprender outra tecnologia seja uma boa solução. O site é feito pela comunidade, e isso se chama "debate". Respeito a opinião dos outros membros e da comunidade que decidiu por manter sua resposta, mas a minha continua a mesma. É importante fornecer uma solução pro problema real enfrentado na pergunta também, além de sugerir uma migração de tecnologia como você fez. A resposta não é ruim, só é incompleta.