# Como deixar sublinhado um caractere específico em um JTextField

Tags: java, swing

Como alterar, digamos, o Font de um ou mais caracteres de um `JTextField` permitindo deixá-los sublinhado, negrito ou itálico? Mas, o resto do texto ficaria normal. Porém nesse caso preciso especificamente deixar sublinhado alguns caracteres de um `JTextField`.

Comment: Pode exemplificar o que quer fazer com algum print? E adicione o que já tentou fazer também para que a pergunta não seja fechada como "ampla demais" ou  "não está clara"

Comment: Ah, JTextField não é possivel fazere isso que você quer, ou altera de todo o texto dele ou não altera de nenhum. Você vai ter que usar JtextPane ou JEditorPane. [**Nesta minha resposta**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/142672/28595) tem um exemplo, veja se lhe serve.

Comment: Você pode utilizar html para destacar apenas alguns caracteres de um texto de alguns componentes Swing (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html).